# Is there an option with php curl to check if it is an initial connection or if this connection is reused?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to check if https connection, is an initial connection or if I reused:

```
$curlHandle = curl_init(); //first connection
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//Reused the handle
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl";
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_close($curlHandle);//finally closed
```

How can I check this (without using wireshark) ? Is there a php curl option to see this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say the connection is re-used this is just because you're requesting a resource on the same domain (wikipedia)? If that's the case then whether the connection is suspended or closed when it's done is probably up to OS policies and not cURL. If you try to access different URLs then I would expect the connection to not be reused. If this is indeed the case then cURL which sits on a higher level of abstraction can't know this.

Comment: Yes, on the same domain. I just want to make sure I'm using an established connection instead of creating a new one for each query, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't. The cURL-Handle isn't saving any informations about that. its just immediately checking if there is an currently used one and returning its handly. It's that way for performance reasons.